# Open documents like pptx, potx, docs etc in browser, where documents hosted on VPN server

Tags: javascript, html, office-app, google-document-viewer

I want to open documents like pptx, potx, word documents etc in browser, where all documents are hosted on VPN server.

I tried both https://docs.google.com/viewer and http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx but didn't get any preview. I may be wrong but I guess this preview is not generated due to documents are hosted on VPN server and Google and MS Office API not able to resolve documents path.

Can anyone help me to either solve this VPN issue or suggest any JS library which supports document preview.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, preview would not be available if your files are hosted on VPN server or you are blocking the outside traffic using firewall.